# Can't open lib '/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64/ivoa27.so Unable to find odbc driver (Netsuite)

Tags: python, django, odbc, netsuite, gunicorn

I have deployed the django project on ubuntu 20.04, nginx , gunicron. A part of the code is not able to run on the server it gives error

```
   ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 
   '/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64/ivoa27.so' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

While the file is available :-

```
xxxx@XXXXXX:/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64$ ls
ddtrc27.so   ivmgan27.so   ivmghu27.so  ivoa27.so      libicudata.so.42  libivoa27m.so   
libodbc.so   openssl810.so
ivldap27.so  ivmgapi27.so  ivoa27.ini   libddicu27.so  libicuuc.so.42    libodbcinst.so  
odbccurs.so
```

It is working fine in the local server. And even in the Server terminal. But it gives error after starting nginx, gunicron service on the domain url. Everything else is working fine.
Below output is from the server terminal

````
```xxxxx@xxxxcc:~$ python3
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyodbc
>>> host = 'xxxxx'
>>> uid = "xxxxx"
>>> role_id = 'xxxxx'
>>> pwd = "xxxxx"
>>> account_id = "xxxxx"
>>> pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={NetSuite};Host='+host+';Port=1708;Encrypted=1;Truststore=/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/cert/ca3.cer;SDSN=NetSuite.com;UID='+uid+';PWD='+pwd+';CustomProperties=AccountID='+account_id+';RoleID='+role_id+'')
<pyodbc.Connection object at 0x7f920414e2d0>
>>> 
```
````

The same code has been used inside the django project and it gives error when checking on domain(URL) after starting the nginx, gunicorn services.

I have tried checking the available drivers using ```odbcinst -j`` the driver is available. Given +777 permission to the directory and all inner files in the /opt/netsuite/.
Creating symlinks, exported paths to .bash_proifile, .bash_rc, /etc/environment. I did whatever I could find on the internet, but still I am not able to solve the issue.

Output of odbcinst -j:-

````
```xxxxxx@xxxxxx:~$ odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.7
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /opt/netsuite/odbcclient/odbc64.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```
````

I found some thread which stated that ubuntu 20.04 has removed /etc/securetty, which may cause PAM failures on SSH/FTP. Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't have /etc/securetty file as I checked.

This is the output of env:-

````
```SHELL=/bin/bash
PWD=XXXXXXX
LOGNAME=xxxxx
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=tty
MOTD_SHOWN=pam
HOME=/home/xxxxxx
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
OASDK_ODBC_HOME=/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64
SSH_CONNECTION=XXXXXXXXXXXX
ODBCINI=/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/odbc64.ini
XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
TERM=xterm-256color
USER=xxxxxx
SHLVL=1
XDG_SESSION_ID=7
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64:/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
SSH_CLIENT=XXXXXXXXXXXX
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/opt/mssql-tools/bin:/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64/:/opt/mssql-tools/bin:/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64/
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/3
_=/usr/bin/env
```
````

I also have Mysql ODBC which is working fine.

The output of **ldd /opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64/ivoa27.so** is:-

````
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fd2292cd000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fd2292c7000)
libicuuc.so.42 => /opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64/libicuuc.so.42 (0x00007fd22906d000)
libicudata.so.42 => /opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64/libicudata.so.42 (0x00007fd228028000)
libpam.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpam.so.0 (0x00007fd228016000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fd227ff3000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fd227e10000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fd227cc1000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fd227ca6000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd227ab4000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd22968d000)
libaudit.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaudit.so.1 (0x00007fd227a88000)
libcap-ng.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcap-ng.so.0 (0x00007fd227a7e000)```
````

Comment: have you tried once after rebooting Ubuntu servers ?

Comment: Yes. I had rebooted the server but still it gives same error. Do you want output of any more file or commands to look more clearly?

Comment: I believe you are able to connect via iSQL utility using this command from Ubuntu CLI $isql -v 'NetSuite' 'user' 'pass', where NetSuite is the DSN name ?. Also, do you have these odbc*.ini files copied under /etc/  directory (/etc$ ls -lt odbc*.ini) ? Another important consideration is to check and run command:- $source oaodbc[64].sh or $source oaodbc[64].csh on the script files oaodbc[64].sh/oaodbc[64].csh. The selection should depend on your preferred shell (sh or csh), if not done already.

Comment: Also try registering the drivers into the system wide ODBC driver repository by running this command:-  $odbcinst -i -d -f /opt/netsuite/odbcclient/odbcinst.ini.

Comment: @ultron Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This typically means that the dependency loading of the shared object failed.  You can test this by using `ldd`, e.g.

```
ldd /opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64/ivoa27.so
```

That will tell you which files could not be resolved when trying load the shared object file.  You can fix this by modifying your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to include the /path/to/ for your netsuite shared objects (I think in your case this would be `/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64`).

Good luck!

Comment: On running above command All dependencies are loading.  And LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable has already included /opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64 , as you can see in original question. Any more suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I didn't see the output of ldd, can you please repost that?

Comment: I have appended the question, can you check please?

Comment: I set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the /opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64. How ever after running ldd ivoa27.so, I am still getting "not found" for certain shared libraries. is there a way to manually add the path ?